# Azure Devops Extension (VSTS) Set a variable that needs to be accessed in next task using Javascript

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to access the variable set in one task from another task in JavaScript.

In the first task I am setting the variable as following:

```
var connection = tl.getInput("connection", true);
if(connection !== undefined) {
   var auth = tl.getEndpointAuthorization(connection, false);
      
   let access_key_1 = auth.parameters["password"];
   let username = auth.parameters["username"]; 
      
   if(auth !== undefined) {
       
   console.log('##vso[task.setvariable variable=access_key_1;]', access_key_1);
}
```

In the second task i am trying to access the variable:

```
console.log(access_key_1);
```

But I am getting error:

```
ReferenceError: access_key_1 is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable you created it's an environment variable, not JS variable.

So, to access it you should use `process.env.access_key_1`. if you to print:

```
console.log(process.env.access_key_1)
```

Comment: Maybe you'll know this one as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834090/azure-pipeline-custom-task-string-input-to-match-regex